# Unable to call Delete Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

When I attempt to call a Delete Web API, I get:

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - /api/tradespendentryip/5
```

My API controller looks like this:

```
public class TradeSpendEntryIPController : ApiController
{
    // DELETE api/tradespendentryip/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        string x = id.ToString(); //I put a breakpoint here which never gets hit
    }
}
```

I call it with this jQuery snippet, hardcoding the hint URL that was generated when I create the Web API:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: "/api/tradespendentryip/5"
                }).done(function( msg ) {
                    alert( 'Record deleted.');
                }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                    alert('Unable to delete this record at this time.');
                });
```

Checking the network tab in Firebug, I always get "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - /api/tradespendentryip/5"

From some research on the web, I tried to adjust my web.config so that WebDAV wouldn't interfere:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Does anyone else know what the issues might be? I also have this event generated in my log which indicates "**Path 'DELETE' is forbidden.**":

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 02/04/2013 1:50:18 PM 
Event time (UTC): 02/04/2013 4:50:18 PM 
Event ID: 646d46d6edab4c049b10948279201c2f 
Event sequence: 42 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
Application domain: 972ee575-22-130093949467510162 
Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: / 
Application Path: C:\Sites\TPS\Development\Source\TPS\Source\TPS.Website\ 
Machine name: MACHINENAME

Process information: 
Process ID: 6532 
Process name: WebDev.WebServer40.exe 
Account name: domain\chardie 

Exception information: 
Exception type: HttpException 
Exception message: Path 'DELETE' is forbidden.
```

at System.Web.HttpMethodNotAllowedHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
       at         System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

```
Request information: 
Request URL: /Canada/TradeSpendingSales/api/tradespendentryip/5 
Request path: /Canada/TradeSpendingSales/api/tradespendentryip/5 
User host address: ::1 
User: domain\chardie 
Is authenticated: True 
Authentication Type: NTLM 
Thread account name: domain\chardie 

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 14 
Thread account name: domain\chardie 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpMethodNotAllowedHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Is this route registered? You can check it using this code `RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes)`

Comment: Well, I had to Google that, but after installing it did indeed show that I was hitting the wrong route. Great tool, really helps since I typically use Glimpse to see how my routes are resolved, but that doesn't work with Web API. This little tool works a treat, it made it worth asking the question!

Answer (score 0):

What web server are you developing in?  I believe the old cassini development server didn't have great support for http verbs besides get and post.  If you are on cassini, give IIS Express a try.

Comment: I am using whatever is integrated with VS 2010

Comment: VS2010 comes with Cassini, so this issue might be what I described.  You can download IISExpress for VS2010 (it came as a part of SP1, but you still need to enable it in your project). http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview